# "Change the features of a CNN into a grid to fed into RNN Encoder?" What is meant by that?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, cnn

So in the paper for OCR pr LaTex formula extraction from image **[What You Get Is What You See: A Visual Markup Decompiler](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04938v1.pdf)**, they pass the features of the CNN into RNN Encoder. But there is problem that rather than passing the features directly, they have proposed a solution to change it into the grid.

**Extract the features from the CNN and then arrange those extracted features in a grid to pass into an RNN encoder.** This is the exact language they have used.

What is meant by that? Theoratically speaking, if I have an `CNN` without any Dense/Fully Connected layer and produces an output of `[batch,m*n*C]`, then how can I change it in the form of a `grid`??  Please see the picture below. So after getting the output from the `CNN`, they have chnged it somehow before passing it to `RNN`. What is the method that one can use to get this transformation?

[image]

So if I have to pass something to `keras.layers.RNN()(that_desired_grid_format)`, what should be this grid format and how can I change it?

Comment: please provide a reference to the paper you mention..

Comment: ![please access it here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04938v1.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems they use a shared RNN which process each row sequentially on the sequence of concatenated channels of individual pixels. From the paper

[image]

## Implementation with channels last

Let the output of the ConvNet be of size `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. The RNN expects an input of size (batch_size, sequence_length, input_size)`. So you have to reshape it with the following correspondence.

```
batch_size*height -> batch_size
channels -> input_size
width -> sequence_length
```

And process each row (along `height` dimension) with the same RNN and concatenate the result.

To do that, we simply reshape to merge the batch and height axis into one dimension so that our RNN will process columns independantly.

```
rnn_input = keras.layers.Reshape((batch_size*height, width, channels))(convnet_output)
rnn_output = keras.layers.RNN(hidden_dim, return_sequences=True)(rnn_input)
```

`rnn_output` will have shape `(batch_size*height, width, hidden_dim)`. You can then combine this tensor into a context vector using a dense layer with tanh activation, as it is written in the paper.

The paper also use trainable initial state for the RNN, [you might be interested in this library](https://pypi.org/project/trainable-initial-state-rnn/) to implement it.

## Implementation with channels first

If you set your `Conv2D` layer with `"channels_first"`, the output `convnet_output` will be of size `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`. Therefore you need first to [permute the dimensions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Permute) before reshaping.

```
convnet_output = keras.layers.Permute((0, 2, 3, 1))(convnet_output)
```

After this step, `convnet_output` has dimension `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. You can then proceed as previously, reshaping and feeding to the RNN.

```
rnn_input = keras.layers.Reshape((batch_size*height, width, channels))(convnet_output)
rnn_output = keras.layers.RNN(hidden_dim, return_sequences=True)(rnn_input)
```

Comment: What if the output of the ConvNet is of size `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`? What Will be the changes to the RNN now? I mean how does the channel first or last affects it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Been searching for it for a long time. I can use the `Show attend Tell: Attention for Captioning` research paper style decoder on my data. They all are same.

Comment: I just updated my answer if you use the default in keras "channels_last" for Conv2D. In this case, it is straightforward, you just need to merge the batch and height dimensions with Reshape.

Comment: If you use "channels_first", you will need to permute dimensions of your tensor before reshaping.

Comment: Hi could you please add that other code for channels last too separately? Actually I'll be able to understand it fully. I mean by analysing what is happening and why it is happening.

Comment: Sure! My first answer was just reshaping but you will actually need permute if you use channels_first, now it should be good :)

Comment: Yeah, but if I could see it side by side channels first and last implementation, it would be better for me to understand what and why has been done. Sorry I did not copy the code you pasted for channels first. Could you please do it again?

Comment: I updated my answer with both channels first and channels last, please check it

Comment: Thanks a lot man. You been the only help I got after 3 weeks.

Comment: I am happy to help :) cheers!

Comment: Hi Adam, I tried using the exact implementation now as I had to leave it in the middle earlier but I'm stuck like a bull in mud. No idea how an where to start. Could you please help me? I have found the `Attention` Code from `tensorflow` but apart from that, I have no idea where to go. [This is the newest link that I have posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456118/how-to-implement-row-encoder-given-in-what-you-get-is-what-you-see-paper-usi)